# Monitor token transfers

Tags: tokens, erc-20

I'd like to monitor the transfers of a certain ERC-20 token but so far I didn't find a way. I'm currently using web3.py. Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One of the winners of the ETHWaterloo Hackaton last year (Nov 2017) was a team called **Rufflet**. They basically built a monitoring tools for smart contracts where you can watch functions & events triggered for a given smart contracts.

**https://rufflet.cryptokitties.co/**

[image]

The following example graph cryptokitties but you can add your contract and monitor it
[image]

Comment: Very buggy. I added another smart contract, but it didn't even switch from CryptoKitties. I couldn't really select _week_, etc. Useless.

Comment: how did that win a hackaton? The front-end was probably more work than the queries lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event. [Solidity Event](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events)

Comment: also, [web3.py event](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#events)

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in monitoring token transfers for large amounts, or to/from an exchange I can suggest you to use **aphrozeus**. It's a website, that monitors token transfers in real-time and filters outlier transactions.

**http://aphrozeus.com**

Comment: Doesn't even load for me.

Comment: consider updating the link or removing it.

Answer (score 0):

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events

```
myContract.events.MyEvent([options][, callback])
```

OR

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html

```
var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    address: '0x123456..',
    topics: ['0x12345...']
}, function(error, result){
    if (!error)
        console.log(result);
});
```