# How to get all kind of transactions happend to/from an address within a time range?

Tags: web3js, transactions, metamask, etherscan, internal-transactions

I'm trying to get all transactions that occured to an address within a specified time range. The transactions shall include all ethers as well as token transactions done to/from an ethereum address.

I tried writing the following code. The minTimeStamp is the time from which I need to get transactions till current time.

Take a quick peak to that:

```
async function getT(minTimestamp) {
minTimestamp = 1592834400;

const transactions = [];
let blockNum, block;

await web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(r => {
    blockNum = r;
});

await web3.eth.getBlock(blockNum).then(r => {
    block = r;
});

while (block.timestamp >= minTimestamp) {
    await new Promise(async(next) => {
        console.log(`[*] Searching block ${blockNum}`);
        if (block && block.transactions) {
            for (let txHash of block.transactions) {
                await new Promise(async(next2) => {
                    let tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash);
                    if (tx.to != null) {
                        if ('0x92376311Ce465c54b26D18C50f8a90734bFB1172'.toLowerCase() === tx.to.toLowerCase()) {
                            console.log(`[+] transaction found on block ${blockNum}`);
                            console.log({
                                address: tx.from,
                                value: web3.utils.fromWei(tx.value, 'ether'),
                                timestamp: new Date()
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    if (tx.from != null) {
                        if ('0x92376311Ce465c54b26D18C50f8a90734bFB1172'.toLowerCase() === tx.from.toLowerCase()) {
                            console.log(`[+] transaction found on block ${blockNum}`);
                            console.log({
                                address: tx.to,
                                value: web3.utils.fromWei(tx.value, 'ether'),
                                timestamp: new Date()
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    next2();
                });
            }
        }

        transactions.push.apply(transactions, block.transactions);

        --blockNum;

        await web3.eth.getBlock(blockNum).then(r => {
            block = r;
        });

        next();
    });
}

console.log('Retreived', transactions.length, 'transactions');
```

}

It works fine although very slow, but I am not able to get token transactions from this code.

Can anyone suggest how I can tweak the code to get that?

Also, if there is any better approach I will appreciate the suggestions.

Thanks, looking forward
Fariha

Comment: You might be better off using something like EthSlurp (http://www.ethslurp.com/) than rolling your own.

Answer (score 2):

**Token transfers**

The challenge with token transfers is that you can't detect them by monitoring the "receiving" address. Tokens are not explicitly transferred to an address - they are only assigned to an address inside the token contract. So whenever someone transfers tokens to address A he actually sends a transaction to the token contract at address T, to function `transfer`. The `transfer` function then simply updates its internal ledger to mark address A as having more tokens.

So to monitor token transfers to address A you have to actually monitor the token contract. But, to make matters more difficult, that only monitors *that one token*. So basically you would have to monitor *every single token contract* to know whether some of them assigns (transfers) tokens to address A.

Fortunately (ERC20) token contracts are supposed to emit `Transfer` event when they transfer tokens so you can add a generic filter to read those events and check their `to` parameter. Here are some examples: [Monitor token transfers](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36713/monitor-token-transfers)

**Performance**

With your current implementation you are halting execution of the code while waiting for every single `Promise` to resolve. So you should be able to improve the performance by adding these Promises to an array and dealing with their results when they come in. That way you would not need to wait for the actual resolving of the previous promise before starting creating/executing the next promise.

The actual implementation is not really a question suited for this forum as it's basically a JavaScript question, but here you can find some examples: https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/347/javascript-promises-mastering-the-asynchronous/how-to-join-promises

Comment: Hi Lauri, thanks for the answer. Can u guide me making the code more fast and optimistic?

Comment: I'd appreciate if u re-edit the code with good performance you mentioned

Comment: I'm not very fluent in web3js and there are possibly other ways to improve the performance, I just gave you one option. And the actual implementation is not really a question for this forum as it has nothing to do with Ethereum but about JavaScript - it's just about handling Javascript Promises. But edited now answer to add a bit more details.